# Finding a right angle in a triangle

Tags: vb.net, math

I am working with the knowledge of all 3 sides of the triangle, they are inputted by the user. And I need to know if any of the angles will equal 90 degrees
I have looked up the math for this but sadly have no idea how to attempt to use it

I am wokring out what kind of triangle the user has with the lengths of each side

```
 If First <> Second AndAlso Second <> Third AndAlso First <> Third Then
     MsgBox("Triangle is scalene")
 ElseIf First = Second AndAlso Second = Third AndAlso First = Third Then
     MsgBox("Triangle is equilateral")
 ElseIf First = Second Or Second = Third Or First = Third Then
     MsgBox("Triangle is isosceles")
 ElseIf rightangle Then
     MsgBox("Triangle is right angle")
 Else
     MsgBox("UFT - Unidentified flying triangle")
 End If
```

I am not sure where to start, not form lack of trying

Comment: You definitely need [trig](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html).

Comment: If what you input  is the angle, then why wont you compare and check that if any of the value equals 90 ?

Comment: @TusharGupta the input variables represent the lengths of the sides, not the angles.

Comment: I looked at that page @HayleyGuillou but I'm not 100% sure how to translate it into my code, but I do understand thats what I need to use

Comment: look for pythagoras theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: Is your only requirement to find a right triangle, or do you need to classify the triangle as well?

Comment: Do you check some special conditions such as some side=0 or negative?

Answer (score 3):

In a right triangle, the sum of the squares of the two shorter sides is equal to the square of the long side. For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2, so a triangle with sides of length 3, 4, and 5 is a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to check using sides. You may need to round off values to avoid problem of floating point comparisons.

```
If First = Math.Sqrt(Second * Second + Third * Third) OrElse Second = Math.Sqrt(First * First + Third * Third) OrElse Third = Math.Sqrt(First * First + Second * Second) Then
    MsgBox("Triangle is right angle")
End If
```

Comment: But I prefer First*First = Second * Second + Third * Third

Comment: Up to you... Precision matters.

Answer (score 0):

Basic outline of what you need to do:

1. Get the three side lengths from the user
2. Find the three angles

   - Use Law of Cosine to find the first angle
   - Use Law of Sine to find the second angle
   - Find the third angle by using 180 - (first + second)
3. Check how many of these angles are 90 degrees and apply any logic you need.

Comment: I understand what is needed...Just not how to do it